# How to use each() for all td in tr, except for the last one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3 tables that every row have 2 \ 4 \ 6 columns , and the last column contains a <kbd>edit</kbd> button.

When I press the <kbd>edit</kbd> button, I want all the other `td`'s will turn into a textboxes.

The script:

```
$(".icon-pencil").click(function () {
    var row = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
    row.find('td').each(function () {
        $(this).html("hi");
    });
});
```

a row example:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <img src="img/couponimg.png" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A coupon for ..</td>
    <td><i class="icon-pencil"></i>
    </td>
    <td><i class="icon-remove"></i>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It works as I want, but it applies the change to all the `<td>` , and I don't want to change the last one.

How to prevent to affect to the last one?

Comment: Have a look at [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/): _Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector._

Comment: If you can, use `closest()` instead of chaining `parent()` calls. Each `parent()` call goes all the way through the DOM tree and then returns the parent, while `closest()` only iterates to the match, then stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and use `:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))` which will EXCLUDE the last 2 columns.

```
$(".icon-pencil").click(function() { 
                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                    row.find('td:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))').each(function() {
                    $(this).html("hi");
                });
            });
```

example :

http://jsbin.com/oyUvAhi/2/edit

2 changes :

- `closest` instead of `.parent('td').parent('tr')`
- when finding the `TR` - select only the relevant TD's for change.

[image]

## Edit

please read @François Wahl comment  - which helps shorten the code :
`row.find('td:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))').html("hi");`

Comment: Is there option to do it until the 2 last children?

Comment: `:not(:nth-last-child(2))`

Comment: @user1798362 Read my new answer.

Comment: @user1798362: If you only want to update all the td elements preceding the one you clicked then use this : `$(this).closest('td').prevAll().html("hi");` no need for `each` - [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/upL3e/)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Just fixed his selector . nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I wasn't talking about your answer - I'm merely responding to OP's comment `Is there option to do it until the 2 last children` - **until** implied all previous until the one you clicked. Instead of adding my own answer I thought I add a little extra info in case it helped. - nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl it was edited. You are welcome to see and test the jsbin which ive attached.

Comment: In addition if it helps any future user - You can drop the `.each()` call as well as the selector already returns a jQuery collection of matched elements, no need to iterate over them a second time - Given the current code in the answer: `row.find('td:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))').html("hi");` does the same thing.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Agree. I will mention it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-pencil', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(:last)').html("hi");
});
```

---

Also,

```
$('something').each(function() {
    $(this).html("hi");
});
```

is equivalent to

```
$('something').html("hi");
```

Comment: Best answer out of all, guaranteed :0

Comment: Why do you  add irrlevant tr's to the click event ?

Comment: @Royi What do you mean?

Comment: @Tomalak not all `.icon-pencil` should have click listenr

Comment: @Royi I'm pretty sure all `.icon-pencil` should react to a click.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
row.find('td').each(function() {
                    $(this).not('td:last-child').html("hi");
                });
```

Comment: I just try to except the last child as OP's question. What do you mean "irrelevant tr's"?

Answer (score 0):

Since your HTML is well formed, in this particular situation, the `:last` CSS selector works nicely, so you can use that. I will give you a more general solution, when the element is not the last node in the parent, or perhaps not even the last node of its type in the parent (`:last-of-type`).

jQuery objects are collections of elements. The CSS selector usually used to create such a collection is matched on the DOM, but once you have a jQuery object you can manipulate it any way you want. If you want to eliminate the last element, you can do something like this:

```
var myJQueryObject = $('mySelector');
Array.prototype.splice.call(myJQueryObject, myJQueryObject.length-2, 2); // removed the last two elements
```

This relies on the fact that jQuery objects are Array-like objects (have a length property and numeric-like keys) and `Array.prototype.*` methods work on Array-like objects.